# How can I solve Codeforce "A. Way Too Long Words" problem?

Tags: c, loops, char, c-strings

The Problem: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/71/A

I tried the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int n, lenght;
  char word[99];
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    gets(word);
    lenght = strlen(word);
    if (lenght > 10) {
      printf("%c", word[0]);
      printf("%d", lenght - 2);
      printf("%c\n", word[lenght - 1]);
    } else {
      printf("%s\n", word);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My code gives me the answer they wanted according to me. But the website doesn't approve my code. I might be mistaken, but I'm still unable to find the problem.

Please, if anyone can spot it, kindly point it to me.

Comment: One error: `for(int i=0; i<=n; i++)` should be `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`

Comment: Another  error: The requirements say "*lengths of from 1 to 100 characters*". But `char word[99];` can only fit words up to 98 characters (with 1 needed for terminating NUL).

Comment: `word` is too short

Comment: @kaylum but if I change word[99] to word[101], the website says, "You have submitted exactly the same code before"

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of the assignment the character array that accepts a string shall have no less than 100 characters. However you declared it as having
only 99 characters

```
char word[99];
```

It should be declared like

```
char word[101];
```

The function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead you need at least to use standard function `fgets`.

The condition of the for loop

```
for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
```

is incorrect. There must be

```
for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
```

After this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

the input buffer contains the new line character `'\n'`. So the next call of `gets` reads an empty string until the new line character is encountered. So the first word is skipped.

I can suggest for example the following solution

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 10, N = 100 };
    
    unsigned int n = 0;
    scanf( "%u ", &n );
    
    while ( n-- )
    {
        char word[N];

        int i = 0;
        
        for ( int c; ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++ )
        {
            word[i] = c;
        }
        
        if ( M < i )
        {
            printf( "%c%d%c\n", word[0], i - 2, word[i - 1] );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%.*s\n", i, word );
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

If the input is

```
4
word
localization
internationalization
pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis
```

then the output is

```
word
l10n
i18n
p43s
```

A more safer for loop in the program can look the following way

```
for ( int c; i < N && ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '\n'; i++ )
```